# Problem installing enum package: "AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute '__version__'"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to install the enum package on my Windows 11 machine with Python version 3.12.1 and pip 23.3, but I got this error:

```
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-p0h71p7l\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-p0h71p7l\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-p0h71p7l\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 480, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-p0h71p7l\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 24, in <module>
      AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute '__version__'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
```

Comment: while you are trying to install the package in `python3`, looks like [enum](https://pypi.org/project/enum/) package currently supports only `python` version 2, hence the install errors..

Answer (score 1):

Just like what [@chickity china chinese chicken said in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77715908/proble-install-enum-on-my-windows-11-machine#comment137010945_77715908), the enum package you're trying to install doesn't support python 3.

But take a look at the Project description of [enum on PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/enum/), **it states that the enum package has been superseded by Python standard library**:

> Python 3 now has in its standard library an enum implementation (also available for older Python versions as the third-party enum34 distribution) that supersedes this library.

So you don't need to install enum as your Python 3.12.1 has inbuilt support for it. See [enum — Support for enumerations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) to see how to use it.